# I want the top menu on page 2 of carousel to not show over the carousel

Tags: jquery, css, carousel

I want the top carousel after you hit the green point, to not cover the whole carousel.

Honestly you will have better change to understand if you do a source view on: www.dijon-egg.com/Possum/

Than on with these pieces of code:

Here is the carousel on P2:

```
            <div class="slide__content">
                    <div class="slide__content-scroller">
                        <img class="slide__img slide__img--large" src="img/1.png"                               alt="Some image" />
                        <div class="slide__details">
                            <h2 class="slide__title slide__title--main">Lorum Lipsum</          h2>
                            <p class="slide__description">Lorumkkkkkk Lipsum</p>
                            <div>
                                <span class="slide__price slide__price--l       arge">Lorum Lipsum</span>
                                <button class="button button--buy">Lorum Lipsum</               button>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /slide__details -->
                    </div><!-- slide__content-scroller -->
                </div><!-- slide__content -->
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `postion: fixed` for the slides and the slider.

Comment: What do I use then

Comment: It is relatives